# Reading dll from web page

Tags: java, google-chrome, dll, pkcs#11

I used Java applet in a web page to load a dll (Pkcs11Wrapper.dll). 
Now,
[Chrome no longer supports NPAPI (technology required for Java applets.)](https://java.com/en/download/faq/chrome.xml)

What can I use to read the dll on my web page?

Thanks for advices!

Comment: What do you use it for? Wouldn't it be better to look for a platform independent solution, as this would only work on Windows machines anyway?

Comment: Yes, you are right. Normally, java applet gets the OS information and uses the specific files (lbpkcs11wrapper.so for linux / Solaris or libpkcs11wrapper.jnilib for MacOS X). But Chrome no longer supports Java applets. Because of this problem, I am searching alternetives to Java applets. Thanks for your advice.

Comment: It's hard to provide an alternative when you don't tell what your program does.

Comment: I want to sign a PDF online with my web page [PaDES](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/PAdES) . So I must reach the X509Certificate in a smart card or token. Lastly, Java applets can do that but Chrome 45 not supports Java Applets. Thanks.